# NSUserDefaults performance concerns

Tags: ios, performance, nsuserdefaults

I have a game and I am constantly saving user progress. It is an extremely fast progressing game and at some points in the game vast user progression may happen 6 times a second, which requires me to store a few progression variables in NSUserDefaults and synchronize 6 times per second. This is working fine on my iPhone6s 64gb, but I fear it may not be something an iPhone4 16gb can handle.

I have no way of testing it though because simulator isn't really accurate with things like this and I don't have a slower device. I also can't seem to find many details about NSUserDefaults preformance reports in the documentation. Does anyone have any knowledge on the topic?

I'm considering storing variables in a local NSDictionary I'll define in my .h and then just saving and synchronizing the NSUserDefaults once during appWillResignActive but I worry about data loss in the event of a crash, device battery dying, etc. I suppose I could have an NSTimer and save the data every 5 seconds or so and also save upon appWillResignActive to minimize loss in the event of a crash; I'd prefer not to have to re-write large amounts of my code though over something that NSUserDefaults may be able to handle just fine on smaller devices.

Comment: Note that calling "synchronize" has nothing to do with writing the data to disk. It is purely to synchronize with another app that is reading and writing the same default store (this is incredibly rare, and for non-Apple apps almost impossible to use on iOS). `synchronize` will soon (finally) be deprecated because it doesn't do anything like what people think it does. See the write-up of proper use of NSUserDefaults from its maintainer: http://dscoder.com/defaults.html

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier I was not aware of that!

Comment: While I agree with the answers, you're calling `synchronize` too much atm,  I'd like to point out that your "concern" is probably unfounded... How many of your users actually still have an iPhone 4? [This link](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/iphone_models/from_date:-20,to_date:0) suggests the market share is only about 1%. I would advise against spending a large amount of your time trying to optimise for 1%

Comment: @RobNapier `synchronize` does persist in-memory changes to disk. In iOS (and probably OS X), it is backed by a plist file. This plist file is updated when `synchronize` is called. Of course `synchronize` is called automatically from time to time by the OS. There are legitimate uses for calling `synchronize` explicitly but not nearly as often as many people mistakenly do. I use it when my app enters the background and to save any critical value that must be persisted even if the app were to crash on the next line of code (and this need is pretty rare).

Comment: @rmaddy According to David Smith (NSUserDefaults maintainer, linked above), NSUserDefaults are written by a separate process, so even if you crash writes are preserved, and "It is almost never necessary to call -synchronize after setting a preference." That's the best information I have on it. It's deprecated anyway ("and will be marked with the NS_DEPRECATED macro in a future release"). See NSUserDefaults.h around line 164.

Comment: @RobNapier Reality says otherwise in my experience. Many times I've tested an iOS app using Xcode and if you kill the app shortly after updating a value in `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults` and then restart the app, the value is lost. This happens because the `NSUserDefaults` didn't have time to persist before the app is killed. This could be due to debugging via Xcode. It could be iOS-specific. I suspect the article you linked to is specific to OS X. All my experience is with iOS, a single app, and using `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults`. There's no app sharing in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call synchronize 6 times a second. (Don't do any disk-based operation 6 times a second.) The system takes care of saving user defaults for you. As you say, calling synchronize in appWillResignActive is reasonable, or between levels.

If you crash, some amount of data loss is to be expected. However, a well written app shouldn't crash. If you're crashing with any regularity, that's your problem, not syncing user defaults. (not saying your app does that)

Comment: Sounds good, so I'll just store to NSUserDefaults frequently and call synchronize every minute or so on a timer and also upon appWillResignActive

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw There is no reason to call `synchronize` every minute unless you are expecting your app to crash regularly.

Comment: @rmaddy I do not expect my app to ever crash ;) But I figure better safe than sorry

Answer (score 7):

`NSUserDefaults` is just an `NSDictionary` in memory. As long as you are not needlessly calling `synchronize` every time you set a value, you won't have any issue. The OS will persist the in-memory representation every once in a while. Certainly not multiple times per second.

So use `NSUserDefaults` as often as you want. Only call `synchronize` at rare times like when your app becomes inactive or enters the background.

Comment: I was calling synchronize every time I saved a variable haha, I'll stop doing that—thanks!

Comment: NSUserDefaults is just an NSDictionary in memory, except it has additional thread safety overheads, and more importantly, it probably has observers watching UserDefaultsDidChange that will get fired on the main thread for every access.  My profiling suggests that this is true even if you haven't added them yourself.